# xcodebuild - run on private simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, xcodebuild

`xcrun simctl --set /path/to/private/folder ...` allows you to manipulate simulators under a private folder: you can use simulators outside of `~/L/Developer/CoreSimulator/`.

How do I make `xcodebuild` use my private simulator set path? I assume there should be some (private?) ENV or CLI flag for that.